# Why Some people in American pronounce “with” like “wth”?

Tags: pronunciation, weak-forms

Eg. she lives with her parents.

I sounds it like: she liveswther parents.

The “i” in “with” is dropped

I add a audio record of "she lives with her parents.".

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ovJt9RobPKmPm6x1Rr2XJ0rGfFVxvJvi/view?usp=sharing

what I listened likes: she liveso ther parents.

Comment: It's not particularly American. Lots of Brits reduce the /i/ of "with" to a neutral vowel schwa when it doesn't carry any stress. Almost all Anglophones reduce unstressed short vowels to schwas in at least *some* contexts.

Comment: You will note that, in your country and language, people have regional/social accents.

Comment: Sounds like a weak form. Do you have a recording or example of this?

Comment: @alphabet That is of course the answer. The real question is [why foreign people learning English **are not being taught** to use weak forms correctly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaXYas58_kc), which makes it hard for natives to understand them and for them to understand natives all due to the huge mismatch in expectations about how English actually works in connected speech. See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22weak+form%22) and [there](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=+%22weak+forms%22) for more, and [more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlbGtEg68x4).

Comment: And because /w/ is a semivowel, it's easy to go straight from it to the next consonant, and you don't need even a reduced vowel.